# Implementing socket.io for realtime notifications

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, socket.io

Trying to send notifications to users, I want to create a system where once the user logs in the socket connects and query's the notification count and then the future notifications get thrown into the socket set process  and increments the current count, once the notifications are opened it should reset the count to 0, and then once the socket is closed the count should be saved into the db and the db should return to just storing the notifications count.

I am using node.js and mongodb server side.

Here is the code I currently have that I am trying to convert to socket.io

```
exports.notificationsNumber = function(req, res) {

        console.log('notifying start');
        Notification.findOne({userId: req.signedCookies.userid}, function(err, user) {
                if(err) {
                        res.send(err);
                        console.log('notifying err');
                } else {
                        console.log('notifying');
                        var notify = user.notifications;
                        res.json(notify);
                }
        });
};
```

App.js file:

```
app.get('/notificationsNumber',  user.notificationsNumber);

var io = require('socket.io');
var connect = require('connect');
var notificationsN = io.listen(server);

notificationsN.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.emit('entrance', {message: 'send notifications Count'});
      socket.on('set nickname', function(name) {
        socket.set('nickname', name, function() {
          socket.emit('ready');
        });
      });
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
      notificationsN.broadcast.emit('exit', {message: 'close connection'});
    });




});
```